# IntellijIDEA, Scala compile server, and make

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

If the scala compile server is enabled in IntelijIDEA (13), is there a need for the "make" in "Before launch" section in the "Run/Debug" configuration dialog?

As in, is it redundant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to make before launch. No it is not redundant.

The "Compiler" panel of "Project Settings" dialog has the option to "Make a project automatically". If that is set (which I am assuming it is in your case) then you will still need to setup run configurations to make before launch.

The reason is that a project is not automatically built when any run configuration is running or debugging. For example, if you have a server started via a run configuration while at the same time you are making changes and re-running a test, no automatic build will occur unless you have set the test's run configuration to make before launch.

See the following post on IntelliJ's developer community for the reason why it was designed this way: ["Make project automatically" - only while not running/debugging](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/440172).